# SSIS: put id = -1 when no matching lookup

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Could anyone tell me how to handle a lookup transformation where there is no matching?

What I need is have the unmatching row insert the row of another table where the ID is -1 (that says this is an unmatched line).

I am doing 7 lookups that follow each other and in each case if the look up fails i'd like to copy the row where the id is -1 from a particular table and continue my processes.

So for example, if there is no matching for the result column between the tables w_kpi and w_check, i'd like to take the line where ID = -1 from the table D_Result .

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help others to answer your question, please add some source code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome. You need to post some more info for us to help you. First, tell us which database language you are using and add it as a tag to your question (always do this). Also, tell us the names of the tables and columns.

Comment: I am doing 7 lookups that follow each other and in each case if the look up fails i'd like to copy the row where the id is -1 from a particular table and continue my processes.

Comment: Ok so for example, if there is no matching for the result column between the tables w_kpi and w_check, i'd like to take the line where ID = -1 from the table D_Result

Comment: I did a bit of rewording, and added the comments into the question (for the future: if you are asked for more information, then *edit* your question). Then: don't explain what your code is doing, if possible, try to give a [mcve].

Comment: ok did you help me ?

Comment: If you ever decide to come back, please have a little more patience. Someone would probably have answered your question eventually. I agree that a lot of the comments above are redundant - it's obvious what you are trying to do. But making comments like that is not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

These steps will let you set the value to -1 if it is missing.

1. Do not fail lookup
2. Add a derived column
3. set the new column to: isnull(lookupValue)?-1:lookupValue

Comment: ok thank you, shall I put the derived column after the lookup or use the derived column as the redirection for entries that do not have matchings

Comment: After. It will go thru lookup with null if not found. I'm confused what you want to do next? If you want to do 2 things then you have to multicast.